# How to format django DateField in model from YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an excel file with over 40 thousand lines to import into MYSQL using a python script and the date format in the excel file is `MM/DD/YYYY` while the corresponding MYSQL field is expecting `YYYY-MM-DD`.
Thefore; it gives the following error on the terminal: `"Incorrect date value: '12/02/1960' for column 'dob' at row 1"`
Is there any django date field option that looks like the following:

```
date = models.DateField(format=MM-DD-YYYY)
```

I used django to create the MYSQL Table with the migration command.

I CANNOT EDIT THE DATES IN THE EXCEL FILE MANUALLY BECAUSE THERE ARE OVER 40,000 LINES.

If is not possible in django, how can I modify it in MYSQL instead?

Or can someone guide me to how to write a python script to sort the dates in the excel date colomn?

Any of these or any other methods are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Comment: Can't you change the format directly in your excel? I mean, you can, is there a reason why you would not?

Comment: @guillermo.. I thought of that but i have over 40 thousand entries in the excel which will take forever to change one by one.

Comment: @roseman.. I wrote a python script that takes the excel file and import its lines into the database.

Comment: You can just change the formatting of the date in excel, you don't need to actually edit the data line by line... Right click on the column header in Excel, Choose format -> date and select the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @simplyvic Codewise provided the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your are using a form to display you can try to customize the dateTime widget by doing this

```
MyForm(Form):

# the default format is %Y-%m-%d
date_available = forms.DateField(
    widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%m/%d/%Y"))
```

[references](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/01/12/django-forms-date-field-format.html)